# Right click "new" registry entry exists, but context menu no longer shows it

Tags: registry

I am running Windows 7. A few months ago I added the following registry key to get a right click "new" option for .tex files

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tex\ShellNew
```

with values

```
(Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
FileName     REG_SZ    C:\Users\myUser\pathToSampleFile.tex
```

and it has been working perfectly. Right clicking and going to the "new" menu gave me the option to create a new .tex file with the desired template.

However, today I uninstalled TeXworks (a text editor for .tex files, if you are not familiar) and the right click "new" option for .tex files disappeared. I thought that it must have deleted the key, but to my surprise the key is *still there*. I tried removing it and putting it back, rebooting, etc., but boilerplate troubleshooting was ineffective.

Does anyone know why this has happened and/or how to fix it? Thank you very much for your time.

Edit: If I search for "ShellNew" in my registry, there are LOTS of file extensions which have the key, but only a few of them actually appear in my right click menu. I think there must be some master on/off key for which file extensions to look to see if they have a "ShellNew" key, but I don't know where it would be.

Comment: Is this `C:\Users\myUser\pathToSampleFile.tex` file still present on your system?

Comment: Yes, it is still present and does not appear to be corrupted in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the option in the "New"-menu to appear you also need to define a filetype for the file extension, i.e. you need to set the default-value in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/.tex to something like TexFile and then add the "TexFile" key to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Then set the default-Value of that key to "TeX-File". The entry in the "New"-menu gets its displayed text this way and windows also displays it as Filetype if you right-click a file and select Properties. Uninstalling TeXworks probably removed that so there is no text to display in the "New"-menu.